# How to control the height of WPF Application window based on the contents of dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have created a WPF application that generate tiles in the second row of grid. What i'm trying to achieve is to keep rendering tiles in the second row without showing the vertical scroll bar, until unless the height of WPF application crosses the resolution of user screen.

```
<Window x:Class="ABC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ABC Installation" MinWidth="620" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="MainWindow_loaded" MinHeight="600" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="56" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" />            
            <RowDefinition Height="94"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Name="productsOuterScroll" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="FormStackPanel">
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

This code renders all the tiles exceeding the user screen window height without a vertical scroll bar.

Any idea how to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on your third row.

Comment: @sumanpathak : i've already tried this. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the mistake. Only two things needed to be done.

1. remove the height attribute from row definition so it should look like this

   ```
   <Window x:Class="ABC.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="ABC Installation" MinWidth="620" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="MainWindow_loaded" MinHeight="600" >


   <Grid>  
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="60" />
          <RowDefinition Height="56" />
          <RowDefinition  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" />
          <RowDefinition Height="94"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <ScrollViewer Name="productsOuterScroll" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
         <StackPanel x:Name="FormStackPanel">
         </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
   ```
2. Setting the max Height dynamically according to the users primary screen height in .cs file

   ```
      double userheightscreen = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
      this.MaxHeight = userheightscreen - 100;
   ```

PS: "-100" is just to leave some space on top and bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to scroll, remove the `Height` from the `RowDefinition` of the row that you are adding content to, and put the content inside the [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx).

Your window might be sizing correctly to the vertical resolution of the screen, but if it's displayed in the center of the screen, it will exceed the height. You can set the startup location to top of the screen with:

```
WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Top="0"
```

If the window height is too high, you might want to set maximum height for your window.

Comment: you are almost right friend but it has nothing to do with the window startup location. the only thing i was missing is to set the max height dynamically according to the users screen and to remove the height attribute from row definition. Thanks for the suggestion, i up voted it.